# firefox quantum web console debug very unreliable

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Trying to debug my angularjs project it seems like the web console debugger is all of a sudden unreliable. I have run into this before and removing firefox dev quantum and reinstall helps, but only for a time. But why do i have to keep uninstalling and reinstalling firefox dev quantum 60?

Whether i check or uncheck "enable source maps", SOMETIMES it stops at my debugger statements and SOMETIMES it dosn't.  SOMETIMES it stops at my breakpoints (when i can set them) and SOMETIMES it dosn't stop at my breakpoints.

In fact, if i uncheck "enable source maps" and i try to click on a line in the quantum web console debugger tab to establish a breakpoint, it just flashes the blue symbol, but the blue symbol does not stay.

I had the warning "WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.", but the thing is quantum web console STILL works SOMETIMES and, even with this message i could see my debugger statements, add a breakpoint, and my project would stop at these breakpoints.

I am a software developer. How hard is for firefox developer quantum programmers to take out the "if" statements that decide whether or not it stops at a javascript debugger statement, or stops at a breakpoint, and allows you to set a break point.

Please refactor firefox quantum web console debugger so that it simply and ALWAYS allows your debugging session to ALWAYS stop at a break point, and to ALWAYS stop at javascript debugger statement, and, to ALWAYS allow you to click to establish a break 
point, and, to ALWAYS stop at a break point?

so frustrating, sometimes i have to stop my development to take time to fix the firefox dev quantum debugger. Then it breaks again!

I have seen some forums that blame some of these issues on the user. PLEASE, it should just work. 
this has begun just recently, i dont know what to do. any advice would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a different browser for your development then.

Comment: Don't mean to sound rude, but that's a cop out. i have been using fire fox debugger for years, its just during the past few weeks that it is not working right. its also a cop out because fire fox simply needs to get its programming act together because reliable software works consistently. I always use fire fox because I think its a very good browser. It can be fixed to be more consistent, its only code. 
thanks for your input.

Comment: Is someone stopping you from using chrome ?

Comment: fire fox has been my applictions gold standard. but, if chrome is better, perhaps we should change up.

Comment: as long as my development works on fire fox, we keep developing, . but, if chrome or something else is better, perhaps we should change up. But in the meantime, the fire fox debugger should STILL JUST WORK! it has had this problem off and on for years. i have to believe i am not the only one having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

thanks all, chrome is MUCH better. Just for others, Chrome debugging actually goes into your visual studio where you can debug your code. it is great.